# Xlwings, run frozen Python

Tags: python, xlwings

I have following Visual Basic code that runs code from a frozen Python module:

```
Sub CVpptx()
   RunFrozenPython ("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\drect\dist\drect\drect.exe")
End Sub
```

The Python code:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings               import  Range
from openpyxl              import load_workbook
from pptx                  import Presentation
from pptx.shapes.autoshape import Shape
from pptx.util             import Inches, Pt
from pptx.dml.color        import ColorFormat, RGBColor
from pptx.enum.shapes      import MSO_SHAPE
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from io import StringIO
from shutil import copyfileobj
import datetime
import subprocess
import sys, os
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
import tkinter


if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
   main_path = sys.executable
else:
   main_path  = __file__[0:__file__.rfind("\\")]


asset_path = main_path   + "\\assets\\"


def add_text_box(slide,left, top, width, height):

    l = Inches(left)
    t = Inches(top)
    w = Inches (width)
    h = Inches (height)
    txBox = slide.shapes.add_textbox(l, t, w, h)
    return txBox



def add_image(photo_path,slide,left, top, width, height):
   l = Inches(left)
   t = Inches(top)
   w = Inches (width)
   h = Inches (height)
   pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(photo_path, l, t, width=w, height=h)
   return pic



def add_text(text,textbox):
  tf = textbox.text_frame
  tf.text = text



def add_slide(prs,type=6, logo=True):   
  slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[type]
  new_slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)
  if (logo):
    add_logo(new_slide)
  return new_slide

def set_design(sp):
  fill = sp.fill
  fill.solid()
  fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0x01, 0x23, 0x45)
  fill.fore_color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR.ACCENT_1
  fill.fore_color.brightness = 0.25
  fill.transparency = 0.25
  sp.fill = None
  fill.background()


def add_shape(s,left, top, width, height):
  shapes = s.shapes
  l  = Inches(left)
  t  = Inches(top)
  w  = Inches(width)
  h  = Inches(height)
  shape = shapes.add_shape(MSO_SHAPE.ROUNDED_RECTANGLE, l, t, w, h)
  return shape


def personal_slide(prs,photo_path):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  add_image(photo_path,s, 0.5, 1, 1.8, 2.5)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)
  spider_chart()  
  skills = add_image(main_path+"temp.png",s, 4, 1, 2, 2.5)
  remove_file(main_path+"temp.png")



def add_logo(s):
  add_image(asset_path+"logo.png",s, 9, 0.2, 0.8, 0.4)

def remove_file(path):
  os.remove(path)

def languages_slide(prs):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)


def programming_slide(prs):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)        

def debug(msg):
  f=open(main_path+"log.txt","a")
  f.write(msg+"\n")
  f.close()



def databases_slide(prs):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)    


def bi_slide(prs):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)   


def ux_slide(prs):
  s   = add_slide(prs)
  allrows=Range("A1").expand()
  for rownum, row in enumerate(allrows.value):
    txbox = add_text_box(s,5, rownum, 3, 2)
    add_text(str(row[1]),txbox)  

def spider_chart():

   cat = ['Analysis', 'Design', 'Production', 'Recipe', 'Project    Management']
   values = [90, 60, 65, 70, 80]

   N = len(cat)

   x_as = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]

   # Because our chart will be circular we need to append a copy of the first 
   # value of each list at the end of each list with data
   values += values[:1]
   x_as += x_as[:1]


   # Set color of axes
   plt.rc('axes', linewidth=0.5, edgecolor="#888888")


   # Create polar plot
   ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)


   # Set clockwise rotation. That is:
   ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
   ax.set_theta_direction(-1)


   # Set position of y-labels
   ax.set_rlabel_position(0)


   # Set color and linestyle of grid
   ax.xaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)
   ax.yaxis.grid(True, color="#888888", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.5)


   # Set number of radial axes and remove labels
   plt.xticks(x_as[:-1], [])

   # Set yticks
  # plt.yticks([20, 40, 60, 80, 100], ["20", "40", "60", "80", "100"])


   # Plot data
   ax.plot(x_as, values, linewidth=0, linestyle='solid', zorder=3)

   # Fill area
   ax.fill(x_as, values, 'b', alpha=0.3)


   # Set axes limits
   plt.ylim(0, 100)


   # Draw ytick labels to make sure they fit properly
   for i in range(N):
       angle_rad = i / float(N) * 2 * pi

       if angle_rad == 0:
           ha, distance_ax = "center", 10
       elif 0 < angle_rad < pi:
           ha, distance_ax = "left", 1
       elif angle_rad == pi:
           ha, distance_ax = "center", 1
       else:
           ha, distance_ax = "right", 1

       ax.text(angle_rad, 100 + distance_ax, cat[i], size=10,  horizontalalignment=ha, verticalalignment="center")
   plt.savefig(main_path+"temp.png",bbox_inches='tight',format='png') 



def save_stringIO(s,path):
  with open (path, 'wb') as fd:
     s.seek (0)
     shutil.copyfileobj (s, fd)



def get_timestamp(): 
  return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y__%H_%M_%S")


def cv_pptx(photo_path):
  debug(main_path)
  prs = Presentation()
  wb = xw.Book.caller()
  candidate=""
  for w in wb.sheets:
    if w.name.find("$")==-1:  
      w.activate()
      if w.name=="Personal":
        personal_slide(prs,photo_path)   
      if w.name=="Languages":
        languages_slide(prs)
      if w.name=="Programming":
        programming_slide(prs)
      if w.name=="Databases":
        databases_slide(prs)
      if w.name=="BI":
        bi_slide(prs)
      if w.name=="Ux":
        ux_slide(prs)  
      presentation=main_path + "cv_"+get_timestamp()+".pptx"
      prs.save(presentation)
      os.system("start "+presentation)
```

I have used Pyinstaller to freeze the Python code. The script is running on
a standard Python 3.6-Anaconda installation. When I call a method of the Python module from the Excel file:

```
RunPython ("import drect; drect.cv_pptx('" & ThisWorkbook.photo_path & "')")'
```

everything works ok, nevertheless when I try to call the frozen exe file:

```
RunFrozenPython ("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\drect\dist\drect\drect.exe")
```

nothing happens. I don't get any error or message. It seems like the code
doesn't execute. When running the exe file no concrete method of the
python module is specified. Is it possible to specify the concrete method
to be run when calling the exe file?

Thank you.

Comment: Just curious how large is the exe file created using xlwings and openpyxl? I find that even basic scripts converted into exe using pyinstaller are 300mb.

Answer (score 1):

When you run "RunPython" you are actually executing the function "cv_pptx". When you run "RunPythonFrozen" you are executing the program itself, but none of the functions have been called. At the end of your file add "cv_pptx()".

You don't need to add the photo_path argument to your function. After you call "wx.Book.caller()" in your function, you can reference the worksheet and cell where the photo path is located in your spreadsheet.

Also, you can test the program before you bundle it into an exe by adding

```
xw.Book(fpath_to_photo).set_mock_caller()
```

Just remove the mock call before you convert it into an exe.